# Using an LSR image on a UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, parallax, tvos

I am creating a tvOS app and I want to use parallax images on a couple of buttons. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/CreatingParallaxArtwork.html):

> To incorporate parallax images in your app:
>
> 1. Create a UIImage object.
> 2. You load the image differently depending on whether the image is included in your app bundle or whether you have downloaded the
>      image.
>
>    - Bundle—Load images using imageNamed:.
>    - Downloaded file—Load images using imageWithContentsOfFile:.
> 3. Create a new UIImageView object using the loaded images.
> 4. If the UIImageView is part of another view, set adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused to YES on the UIImageView.

I know it says `UIImageView` there, but I was hoping to make the same effect happen on a `UIButton`, like the home screen app icons.

I've created the artwork, made a stack in the asset catalog, and loaded the image with `imageNamed:`, but the `UIButton` does not behave like a parallax image. It does not sway around like the home-screen icons do. It just looks like a flat image.

Is there something else I have to enable in order for the `UIButton` to behave like the home screen app icons?

```
UIButton* quitGame = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rectWithNewX(playAgain.frame, 985)];
[quitGame setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"quit.lsr"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[quitGame setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:YES];
fadeIn(quitGame, self.view, 0.5);
```

Comment: `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` is really the key here, and it's only available on UIImageView. You could implement it yourself, but that would be a pain. You might have better luck making a custom control that's a UIImageView which acts like a button. And/or you could [file a feature request](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: @jtbandes I'll probably submit a feature request, **but** I did find a workaround. If you make an LSR UIImageView and then make that a subview of the button, it works.

Comment: Yes, but do you get the correct pressed state?

Comment: @jtbandes Yes you actually do.

Comment: 2022 you can now just set that on a button. You have to do it programmatically. `testButton.imageView?.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of right now, this is not possible with just UIButtons, however, I did find a workaround.

Instead, create a UIImageView that will fill the size of the UIButton and make it a subview of the UIButton. Then call the `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused:` and set it to true. Voila!

```
UIButton* playAgain = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(centerX(650, self.view), sh() - 250, 300, 180)];
[playAgain setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:YES];
[playAgain addTarget:self action:@selector(playAgain) forControlEvents:UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered];
fadeIn(playAgain, self.view, 0.5);

UIImageView* playAgainIGV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 180)];
[playAgainIGV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playagain.lsr"]];
[playAgainIGV setAdjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused:YES];
[playAgain addSubview:playAgainIGV];
```

Comment: Why add an extra `UIImageView` as a subview? Just use `-setImage:forState:` and set `playAgain.imageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` to `YES`.

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues when setting files or precompiled LSRs.

Creating the LSR in XCode Asset Catalogue through Asset Catalogue -> New Apple TV Image Stack and dragging in the PNGs, then setting the image either through Interface Builder or through this works:

```
-(void) setLsr:(UIButton *)button lsrNamed:(NSString *)lsr {
    [button setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:YES];

    UIImageView *biv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height)];
    [biv setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:lsr]];
    [biv setAdjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused:YES];
    [button addSubview:biv];
}
```

Comment: No need to add your own `UIImageView`, you can use the built-in `button.imageView`. (see my other comment somewhere above)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the answer of [david](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32731318/657988) I made a simple **Swift** method to create a **parallax effect button**:

```
func createParallaxButton(button: UIButton, imageNamed: String) {
        button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = true
        let buttonBg = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: imageNamed))
        buttonBg.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true
        buttonBg.frame = button.bounds
        button.addSubview(buttonBg)
    }
createParallaxButton(myButton, imageNamed: "myButtonimage.lsr")
```